# Limit comments displayed on basis of user_id

Tags: customization, comments

How can i limit comments displayed on the page - `reviews` by `author_id`.

Lets say that the `author_id` to limit to is in variable `$author_id_to_limit`.

Please tell me how to hook the function to do so.

I would even like to know how to edit the no of post with this cuurent query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The `pre_get_comments` hook

Note that the single post's comments are fetched with `get_comments()`, within the `comment_template()` function.

The `get_comments()` function is just a `WP_Comment_Query` object wrapper, so we can restrict the comment query with the `pre_get_comments` hook.

### Example #1

Here's a simple `user_id` restriction example:

```
! is_admin() && add_action( 'pre_get_comments', function( \WP_Comment_Query $q )
{
    if( $uid = get_query_var( 'author_id_to_limit' ) )
        $q->query_vars['user_id'] = (int) $uid; 
});
```

where you might add further constraints, so you don't modify other comment lists.

### Example #2

We could restrict it more with:

```
// Let's begin where the main loop starts:
add_action( 'loop_start', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    // Target the main loop
    if( ! in_the_loop() )
        return;

    // Modify the get_comments() call
    add_action( 'pre_get_comments', function( \WP_Comment_Query $q )
    {
        if( 
               $uid = get_query_var( 'author_id_to_limit' )   // Get the user input
            && ! did_action( 'wpse_mods' )                    // Run this only once

        ) {
            // Set the comment user id
            $q->query_vars['user_id'] = (int) $uid; 

            // Activate the temporary action
            do_action( 'wpse_mods' );
        }
    });
});
```

i.e. we want to target the first `get_comments()` call after the main loop starts.

You might use other hooks, some themes have specific hooks that might be easier to target.

### Modify the comments count accordingly

If we want to modify the displayed comments number, then we could  use the `get_comments_number` filter.

The `get_comments_number()` function uses the `comment_count` property of the $post object, that originates from the `wp_posts` table. So that will not help us here.

We can instead re-use the comments query, to update the comment number, exactly when our temporary `wpse_mods` action as fired only once (you might have to adjust that to your needs)

```
! is_admin() && add_action( 'the_comments', function( $comments, \WP_Comment_Query $q )
{
    $request = $q->request;

    add_filter( 'get_comments_number', function( $number ) use ( $request ) 
    {
        // Override the comments number after our previous modifications
        if( 1 === did_action( 'wpse_mods' ) )
        {                   
            global $wpdb;       
            // Modify the comments query to our needs:
            $number = $wpdb->get_var( 
                str_replace( 
                    'SELECT * ', 
                    'SELECT COUNT(*) ', 
                    $request 
                )
            );
        }
        return $number;
    } );        
    return $comments;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: i have updated my question...please help me with no of comments too

Comment: Please check out the updated the answer @ShahrukhKhan

Comment: I have posted my further query over this on this [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202457/get-number-of-comments-after-modifying-comment-query). Please help me with it.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Just need to make your function to get comments and then use your function output at required places.

```
<?php get_comments( $args ); ?>

<?php $args = array(
'user_id' => $author_id_to_limit, ); 

get_comments( $args ); ?>
```

Set Number to your variable like I did in above code. Rest of args please put accordingly.

For details follow this link below:

[get_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)