# Not work hide comments with future date

Tags: date

My code not work. How to correct code?

```
function filter_where( $where = '') {
      $where .= " AND wp_comments.comment_date < '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'";
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_comments', 'filter_where' );
```

[image]

Sorry for My English.

Comment: At the very least you need to `return $where;`

Comment: However the argument isn't the where string, it's a WP_Comment_Query: [pre_get_comments documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_comments/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit comments displayed on basis of user\_id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202418/limit-comments-displayed-on-basis-of-user-id)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not using the action hook at all in the proper way. You'll want to create `date_query` parameters and add this to the comment query.

Here is what you can do to achieve this so that only comments created before "right now" are queried:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', function ( $commentQuery ) {
    $commentQuery->query_vars[ 'date_query' ] = [
        [
            'before' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
        ],
    ];
} );
```